# How to find the dependencies in .cabal when using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm learning Haskell these days. And I a interesting project in Github : https://github.com/tmishima/Hinecraft 
I clone it , and I want to build it myself and run it. But I encounter with stack-build problems like that

```
Resolver 'lts-13.0' does not have all the packages to match your requirements.
FTGL not found
    - Hinecraft requires -any
GLUtil not found
    - Hinecraft requires -any
OpenGLRaw version 3.3.1.0 found
    - Hinecraft requires <=2.3.0.0
```

It looks like these dependencies can not be found in stack , what should I do now ? Should I download these dependencies manually and build them locally?
Thanks for help.

the .cabal dependencies code

```
build-depends:       
                 base , GLFW-b , OpenGL , mtl
                 , bytestring , array , vector , directory
                 , process , OpenGLRaw <= 2.3.0.0 , cereal , FTGL
                 , time , containers , GLUtil , linear , text
                 , sqlite-simple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those dependencies are not included in the package set of stackage (you can check it in https://www.stackage.org/lts-13.0).
However, they are in the hackage repository (f.e. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=GLUtil) and you can make stack using them adding a `extra-deps` section in the `stack.yaml` config file:

```
resolver: lts-13.0
extra-deps:
  - FTGL-2.1
  - GLUtil-0.10.3
  - OpenGLRaw-2.3.0.0
```

<strike>I've not tested the build, maybe it could fail cause dependencies are not compatible.</strike>

I've tried building the package and the above configuration doesn't work. The [actual cabal file](https://github.com/tmishima/Hinecraft/blob/master/Hinecraft.cabal) doesn't have the `OpenGLRaw <= 2.3.0.0` constraint, maybe did you add the constraint for some reason?

If not so you could try build it removing the constraint from cabal file and with this `stack.yaml`, that uses the default `OpenGLRaw-3.3.1.0`:

```
resolver: lts-13.0
extra-deps:
  - FTGL-2.1
  - GLUtil-0.10.3
```

As the package needs an older version of `OpenGLRaw` (2.3.0.0), i've managed to define a config file that uses that version, using `lts-6.35`:

```
resolver: lts-6.35
extra-deps:
 - FTGL-2.1
 - GLURaw-1.4.0.2
 - GLUtil-0.8.8
 - hpp-0.3.1.0
 - OpenGL-2.13.0.0
 - OpenGLRaw-2.3.0.0
```

Hope it helps!

As a side note, i have to mention that `cabal` is able to build the package with the original constraint, with not further configuration (although it picks different versions of libs).

Comment: Thanks, it can run to compile.But it looks like the project's dependencies are old, and it throws some exception that some data struct could not be found.

Comment: I've added a last stack.yaml that honor the original constraint over `OpenGLRaw` (see the edited answer)

Comment: oh thanks, I'm trying on it. To do this, I have to download lts-6.35, but it goes slow..